# How can I know I'm online, in ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I have configured ejabberd to work in multiple tabs by passing different **resource** for each connection in each tab (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/sstrigler/JSJaC/issues/45) by **rraptorr**). And it works fine in each tab.

The problem now is, if I close 1 tab, then a presence offline stanza is sent to other users saying that I'm offline, where as I'm online in other tabs with different resource.

**Question:** Is there a way to detect if I'm online, using my jid?

Answer (score 1):

XMPP is a multi resources / multi-connection protocol. A client is not supposed to take only the last presence receive into account but keep a list of all connected resource for his contact. That way, when a presence unavailable is received, it need to make sure only the associated resource is mark offline, not all resources from the user.

Comment: @[Mickaël Rémond](http://stackoverflow.com/users/559289/micka%c3%abl-r%c3%a9mond) Thanks for the reply. I understand what you are trying to say, but if I follow your suggestion, then I need to know the list of resources that a particular user is connected with. I don't know how to retrieve that. Can you help? An example will be great.

Comment: For each resource connected, you will receive a different presence available. You just need to cache them properly. You cannot retrieve a list, you need to keep an up to date view of each users connected resources in your client.